# Whether OrientDB is Active and competing?

Tags: orientdb

Whether OrientDB graph database software is active and competing, I am not getting any response from their community forum, also no reply from their enquiries email, and couldn't find much in stack overflow in last 2-3 years.

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB is under active development and competing. 
The community forum is active as well, please give me a reference to your posts and I'll see if I can help you